# Contractions which are conformal

Tags: fractals

Can someone give an example for a contraction which is also a conformal? 
I know that we call a contraction as conformal when it preserves angles. 
Even a hint would be helpful.

Comment: $x\mapsto x/2$?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your request, $z\mapsto\frac12z$ is both a contraction and a conformal map from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$.